# Use Kotlin/JS's new IR Compiler with Maven?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, maven

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.9.10</kotlin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>js</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here's the error message that I get when I try to use `mvn compile`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.9.10:js (compile) on project artifact: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] Old Kotlin/JS compiler is no longer supported. Please migrate to the new JS IR backend

The issue is, the docs online for using kotlin-maven-plugin don't say anything about how to actually do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out how to do it by running this command:

```
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.jetbrains.kotlin -DartifactId=kotlin-maven-plugin -Ddetail=true
```

Checking that, I learned that the `kotlin:js` goal respects the configuration parameter `useIrBackend`, which defaults to `false` if it's not specified.

Changing the plugin element in the pom.xml to this fixed it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <useIrBackend>true</useIrBackend>  <!-- The important line -->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>js</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```